# What kind of resin can be used to fill a gap in a piece of wood?

Tags: material-selection, wood, woodworking

If filling a piece of natural wood with grooves in with resin - clear or coloured - what is the best kind to use? This would need to allow for the wood to be used as a table top.

Answer (score 3):

An **epoxy resin**, or polyepoxide: a resin mixed with a hardener.
This can be used both for filling in gaps in wood as well as encasing wood.

> Epoxy can give wood a waterproof, resilient finish. In most cases, it is an ideal coating for wood projects that will be exposed to moisture or wear. ([source](https://www.hunker.com/13418767/how-to-seal-wood-with-epoxy-resin))

Some epoxies are intended for use with wood, or, more specifically, wooden furniture (called '*tabletop epoxy*', for example), and will be clearer, more UV-resistant, and less prone to forming bubbles.

Whether coloured or clear is a matter of taste.

If you're thinking of casting the entire piece of wood in resin, you can calculate how much you are going to need [here](https://epoxycountertopdiy.com/epoxy-resin-coverage-calculator/) (NB that's a commercial website).

Comment: When I was doing carpentry we used a lot of [West System Epoxies.](https://www.westsystem.com/) They have multiple types of fillers to do exactly this.